# Cannot access global variable in typescript

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, ecmascript-6, typescript2.0

I have a weird problem in the code. I declared markers variable inside a class so it is global and can be accessed everywhere inside class. But the problem is that I can access markers inside initMap but cannot access it inside function of InitMap. Error tells: TS2339 Property 'markers' does not exist on type void

```
 export class StudentGraphicReportMapComponent implements OnInit  {
  locations: any[] = [];
  markers:any[] = [];
  constructor(private http: Http, private  elementRef: ElementRef , private dashboardService: DashboardService) {
  }
  initMap() { 
   // ------ CAN ACCESS markers here
 
    this.locations.forEach(function(location: Location) {
         for ( let b = 0; b < location.studentCount; b++) {
           let marker = new google.maps.Marker({
             position: location,
             label: 'A'
           });
    // ----------CANNOT ACCESS markers here
           this.markers.push(marker); //Error:Property 'markers' does not exist on type void
         }
    });
  
  }
  ngOnInit() {
    this.dashboardService.getStudentCoordinates().then(data => {
      this.locations = data.data;
      this.initMap();
    });
  }

}
```

Please help me to solve this problem. Kind regards

Comment: You should check out **this**: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20279484/how-to-access-the-correct-this-inside-a-callback (pun intended :P )

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should use [arrow functions](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/functions.html#this) to get access to the `this` like this:

```
export class StudentGraphicReportMapComponent implements OnInit  {
  locations: any[] = [];
  markers:any[] = [];
  constructor(private http: Http, private  elementRef: ElementRef , private dashboardService: DashboardService) {
  }
  initMap() { 
    this.locations.forEach((location: Location) => {
         for ( let b = 0; b < location.studentCount; b++) {
           let marker = new google.maps.Marker({
             position: location,
             label: 'A'
           });
           this.markers.push(marker); //Error:Property 'markers' does not exist on type void
         }
    });

  }
  ngOnInit() {
    this.dashboardService.getStudentCoordinates().then(data => {
      this.locations = data.data;
      this.initMap();
    });
  }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Make local variable points to this

```
initMap() { 
let _self = this;
...
}
```

and use `_self.markers` inside function